# How can I check if a radio button is selected in jQuery and gets his value?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Can you please explain me how I can check in jQuery if a radio button is checked and get the value before inserting the value in a database?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the relevant code? Also, your validation should **not** rely on JavaScript. However, having a JS validation to prevent a form from being submit + a serverside validation is fine.

Comment: Don't create new profile if your first question is not accepted you just posted a few min. ago because this one is also not going to accepted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429001/validate-if-all-yes-no-radio-button-groups-are-checked-and-validate-if-all-are-y

Comment: hmmmm then sorry i think that because this question is 75% same with that and just posted after few mins.

Answer (score 2):

To see if a radio input is checked:

```
$("#radio").is(":checked"); // returns boolean
```

The get the value of the radio group inputs by class:

```
$(".radioGroup:checked").val(); // returns checked radios value
```

or by using the attribute selector:

```
$("input[name=radioName]:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#radiobuttonid").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        //radion button is selected do something
        var radioButton = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

agreed with @RobW on this...however to answer your query you could use the jquery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or the [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) methods

```
if($('your-elem-id').prop("checked")) { //form submit }
```

should help

Answer (score 0):

```
bFlag = $('#test2').is(':checked');
```